# Passing String Array to A Robotium Class

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I am automating a product using Robotium. In a module I have to validate the data derived.

For that I am using this code:

```
class sharefirstlevel {

    public void A {
        for(int k=1;k<=4;k+=2) {
            ExpectedResult = solo.clickInList(k);
            for (int i = 0; i < ExpectedResult.size(); i++) {
                Actualvalues[i] += ExpectedResult.get(i).getText().toString() + " ";
                solo.scrollListToLine(0, k);    
                ExpectedResult=solo.clickInList(1);
                Actualvalues[i] += ExpectedResult.get(i).getText().toString() + " ";
                ExpectedResult = solo.clickInList(2);
                Actualvalues[i]  += ExpectedResult.get(i).getText().toString() + " ";
                Log.d("xyz","Values of the Strings are"+Actualvalues[i].toString());    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its extracting the values selected to an array.

Now when its derived, to validate I am using this code:

```
class sharedLevel {
    public void B {
        for(int i=0; i <= sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues.length; i++) {
            Log.d("xyz","Values are:"+sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues[i]);
            actual=solo.searchText(sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues[i]);
            assertEquals(expected, actual);
            Log.d("xyz","Values are:"+sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But the thing is in the first part of code proper values are extracted to the Array.
In the second part of code when I am passing the array values, I am not getting the values but the memory allocation object. Hence the test case is failing.

Please help me. Am at a fix !!

Comment: Whoa the question changed completely? Were you able to solve the first problem?

Comment: This question and its recent edits are currently under discussion [in this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194327/rule-on-changing-a-question-after-a-bounty-was-raised).

Comment: @Slartibartfast: I was able to solve my previous question. But the null pointer exception is the problem now. Please help me

Comment: No, Priety, that's not how these sites work. As for changing the question, please see the link in Bart's comment. Also please note that this is a Q&A site, in which ALL questions should ALWAYS have some value for future visitors as well. By changing the question you're kind of indicating that your previous question was not worth reading by future visitors? If true, then your question was not a good question for this site. (Now that you agreed you changed the question, I've rolled back the changes you made. If @Slartibartfast's answer helped you solve the previous issue, then please award him.)

Comment: @Priety it is frowned upon to completely change a question once answers have been posted - bounty or not (see the meta link). Instead if the answers solve your original problem, please accept it and then ask another question if you need to solve another problem.

Comment: Arjan, thanks for the suggestions. Its fine for me, that you have reverted back the question. But I was able to solve the problem on my own. So I just upvoted sebastian question and din't accept. Thanks for the suggestion. I won't edit the questions

Comment: But then if you solved the problem yourself, why not post your solution as an answer, and accept that one? Again, please note this site aims to be a Question & Answer resource for future visitors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem. The change which I had to make in Class B was

```
for(int i=1;i<sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues.length;i++){
  Log.d("Pratibha","Values are:"+sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues[i]);
  actual=solo.searchText(sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues[i]);
  assertEquals(expected, actual);
  Log.d("TAG","Values are:"+sharefirstlevel.Actualvalues[i]);
}
```

And hence I am getting the values of the array in class B. Because the index started from 0, and I din't have any text values at 0th position, It was returning garbage values.

Thanks all for the responses.

Answer (score 4):

How about using

```
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expected, actual));
```

**EDIT:** This answer is for the question for which the bounty was raised and not the edited question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18334315/revisions)

Comment: I was able to solve my previous question. But the null pointer exception is the problem now. Please help me

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: Slartibartfast, I was able to solve the problem on my own. So Idin't accept your answer. Thanks for the suggestion. I won't edit the questions

Comment: Not a problem , but the point of keeping this thread here is now to help other people who have similar problems, so the norm is to either ACCEPT the answer if it solved your problem OR write your own answer if its different and ACCEPT it so that it helps people. But in case of a bounty you will not get the points back if you do the latter and the +50 is just lost, unless another answer gets a lot of upvotes >2 and is awarded half the bounty. But if your answer is better, it will get upvotes. It may even earn a separate bounty at some point from another user who finds it exceptionally useful

Comment: Sure Slartibartfast, I will post my answer once am back at work tomorrow. I will try the answer given by you. If my null pointer exception is solved by it, I will surely accept it. Thanks a lot :-) Sorry for the Editing

Comment: But unfortunately your null pointer exception is a completely different question and this answer does not solve it but solves your original question problem :/ Not a problem anyway. Thanks.